# npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN error when trying to install express

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm learning web development by going through a course and it was time to install express using node package manager. I had to install express and used the following command:

```
npm install express
```

and I got an error that said:

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN

npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN

npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-21T08_32_35_6
54Z-debug.log
```

---

I'm totally lost at the moment. Please don't judge me as I'm still extremely new to Node. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I've enhanced the question a bit as I could. Remember to add more details if possible because there are unknown reasons to occur such error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the fix myself and what I basically did was use a different internet connection and I was able to install express! Hopefully someone else finds this useful!

Comment: restart helped me, since I have not made any changes for this to happen, and it was perfectly working a moment ago, restart seemed a good option.

Comment: indeed, the choice/configuration of the VPN, if any, can also be related

Comment: I turned on my mobile hotspot and connected through that. It worked.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue and I just solved it with command sets that I found on the internet.
I am sharing it to save your time.

```
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy --tried removing npm proxy
```

I am sorry I can't add more detail to it, but this solved my issue of:

```
npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: getaddrinfo 
EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
```

Comment: Did not work here

Comment: then you might have another problem, this worked for me a couple of years ago. Looking at upvote, it looks like it helped others as well so it seems one of the valid solutions.

I remember that one of the valid solutions that worked for other people was changing the internet connection. I mean connect to another internet or hotspot and try installing.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MicroSoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo?redirectedfrom=MSDN) EAI_AGAIN error code translate to temporary failure in name resolution, that is a DNS issue.
So check network configuration and if possible switch to a different network.

Comment: I've fixed the error. I just used a different internet connection and it worked and I was able to download Express

Comment: this is like magic. any idea how & why this worked?

Answer (score 2):

This will happen the slowness of your internet connection. My code worked after closing other browser tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Can also confirm this was a network DNS issue. On Windows you can attempt to run

```
ipconfig /renew
```

but failing that, a restart of the machine or router should resolve the issue, otherwise contact your network admin.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused due to network issues, so in windows operating system run Troubleshooter, you may find errors like "Your DNS Server Might Be Unavailable". If you get this error, please reset your Network adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following command, it worked for me:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a proxy issue for me, as the top comment suggests. I'm behind a corporate proxy, so I need to set a proxy for `npm` to work.

```bash
# Set proxy. Don't forget the http://!
npm config set proxy http://127.0.0.1:<port>
npm config set https-proxy http://127.0.0.1:<port>
# Unset proxy
npm config rm proxy 
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Answer (score -1):

```
UN  npm install:                                                      
#0 108.1 npm ERR! code EAI_AGAIN                                                
#0 108.1 npm ERR! syscall getaddrinfo                                           
#0 108.1 npm ERR! errno EAI_AGAIN                                               
#0 108.1 npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/yargs-parser/-/yargs-parser-13.1.2.tgz failed, reason: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN registry.npmjs.org
#0 108.
```

2

Getting this error while building docker container?

Dockerfile:-
FROM node:lts
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN  npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm","run","development"]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).