# unable to install material-ui/core in reactjs project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, material-design, mern

I try to install material-UI on my new project but got an error.
I tried with `--force` tag but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Please post text as text rather than pictures of text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63010779/438992

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010779/npm-err-code-eai-again-error-when-trying-to-install-express This might solve your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERR! code EAI\_AGAIN error when trying to install express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63010779/npm-err-code-eai-again-error-when-trying-to-install-express)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the links in the comments, it's a DNS issue.  You can troubleshoot it by:

1. Open a command prompt (windows) or terminal (mac/linux)
2. Type `nslookup`
3. Next type `registry.npmjs.org`
4. If it doesn't respond with an IP address and says, non-existent domain type `server 8.8.8.8` (this is google's public dns server)
5. Type `registry.npmjs.org` and it should return the IP.  This confirms it's an issue with the dns server you're using.

If that's the case, you can try setting your machine's DNS server to use 8.8.8.8 and run the install.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any proxy set, if yes remove them

to check if you have proxy,

```
npm config list
```

to remove proxy,

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Another silly thing to try would be to disconnect from your network/wireless and **connect through mobile hotspot** and check.